# Statically link C++ 2010 failed

Tags: c++

My goal is to avoid the installation of Microsoft C++ 2010 by statically link it. Because I don't know if that package will be installed on all the customer computers and his IT department doesn't allow the installation of software.

One other alternative would be to avoid the use of administrative privilege. (extract dll in the same directory that my program for example)

I found one possible solution http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/ab187afb-3af0-44ba-a03c-dde9e5208a1a/ and I tryied the parameter /MT.

I've 2 errors :

> Erreur    1   error LNK2019: symbole externe non rÚsolu __CrtDbgReportW
>   rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction "void __cdecl std::_Debug_message(wchar_t
>   const *,wchar_t const *,unsigned int)"
>   (?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z)    C:\Users\philippe\Downloads\Portable
>   Devices COM API Sample\C++\libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) WpdApiSample
>
> Erreur    2   error LNK1120: 1 externes non
>   rÚsolus   C:\Users\philippe\Downloads\Portable Devices COM API
>   Sample\C++\Debug\WpdApiSample.exe 1   1   WpdApiSample

Am I in the good way ? And how can I resolve that problem ?

Comment: First, you want to build a release build, not a debug build, if you are going to distribute your software at all!

Comment: well you are right. I have no more error while compiling. How can I verify that it doesn't need the use of the Microsoft runtime ?

Comment: Use the Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect your program. Make sure you don't see any `msvcrt*.dll` entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `_CrtDbgReportW` at the "requirement" section says:

> **Libraries:** Debug versions of C run-time libraries only.

It means that such function are not present in the release version of the libraries, hence, the release version of your code should not call them.

According to [**this table**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) may be you shold use `/MTd` so that you will link to the static debug version.

Comment: With /MT in release it worked very well. I use the dependency walker and I found that the msvcrt*.dll wasn't use.

Answer (score 1):

/MT for release configuration, /MTd for debug